# Problems upgrading Python from 2.7.12 to 3.4.2 on Lubuntu 16.10

Tags: python, ubuntu, upgrade

I'm having problems upgrading Python from 2.7.12 to 3.4.2 on my Lubuntu 16.10 machine. I'm a Linux noob so was hoping that the update was as simple as apt-get update...then read somewhere that apt-get install would remove older versions and replace with the newer version. So I tried it, but this is what I got:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python 3.4.2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libdc1394-22' for regex '3.4.2'
Note, selecting 'libdc1394-22-dbg' for regex '3.4.2'
Note, selecting 'libdc1394-22-dev' for regex '3.4.2'
Note, selecting 'libdc1394-22-doc' for regex '3.4.2'
Note, selecting 'libghc-adjunctions-dev-4.3-4e2a8:i386' for regex '3.4.2'
Note, selecting 'libdc1394-20-dev' for regex '3.4.2'
Note, selecting 'libghc-adjunctions-prof-4.3-4e2a8:i386' for regex '3.4.2'
Note, selecting 'libghc-monadcatchio-transformers-prof-0.3.1.3-4c2d4:i386' for regex '3.4.2'
Note, selecting 'libghc-monadcatchio-transformers-dev-0.3.1.3-4c2d4:i386' for regex '3.4.2'
Note, selecting 'libghc-adjunctions-dev:i386' instead of 'libghc-adjunctions-dev-4.3-4e2a8:i386'
Note, selecting 'libghc-adjunctions-prof:i386' instead of 'libghc-adjunctions-prof-4.3-4e2a8:i386'
Note, selecting 'libghc-monadcatchio-transformers-dev:i386' instead of 'libghc-monadcatchio-transformers-dev-0.3.1.3-4c2d4:i386'
Note, selecting 'libghc-monadcatchio-transformers-prof:i386' instead of 'libghc-monadcatchio-transformers-prof-0.3.1.3-4c2d4:i386'
python is already the newest version (2.7.11-2).
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 libdc1394-22-dev : Depends: libraw1394-dev but it is not going to be installed
 libghc-adjunctions-dev:i386 : Depends: libghc-array-dev-0.5.1.0-98220:i386
                               Depends: libghc-base-dev-4.8.2.0-a3ce8:i386
                               Depends: libghc-comonad-dev-4.2.7.2-48e3c:i386
                               Depends: libghc-containers-dev-0.5.6.2-5879d:i386
                               Depends: libghc-contravariant-dev-1.4-fd0fc:i386
                               Depends: libghc-distributive-dev-0.5.0.2-5a38b:i386
                               Depends: libghc-free-dev-4.12.4-5b9a8:i386
                               Depends: libghc-mtl-dev-2.2.1-05005:i386
                               Depends: libghc-profunctors-dev-5.2-04b6a:i386
                               Depends: libghc-semigroupoids-dev-5.0.1-71922:i386
                               Depends: libghc-semigroups-dev-0.18.1-1d980:i386
                               Depends: libghc-tagged-dev-0.8.4-b253b:i386
                               Depends: libghc-transformers-dev-0.4.2.0-a5bbd:i386
                               Depends: libghc-transformers-compat-dev-0.4.0.4-8aa40:i386
                               Depends: libghc-void-dev-0.7.1-dfe8d:i386
                               Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.0) but it is not going to be installed
 libghc-adjunctions-prof:i386 : Depends: libghc-array-prof-0.5.1.0-98220:i386
                                Depends: libghc-base-prof-4.8.2.0-a3ce8:i386
                                Depends: libghc-comonad-prof-4.2.7.2-48e3c:i386
                                Depends: libghc-containers-prof-0.5.6.2-5879d:i386
                                Depends: libghc-contravariant-prof-1.4-fd0fc:i386
                                Depends: libghc-distributive-prof-0.5.0.2-5a38b:i386
                                Depends: libghc-free-prof-4.12.4-5b9a8:i386
                                Depends: libghc-mtl-prof-2.2.1-05005:i386
                                Depends: libghc-profunctors-prof-5.2-04b6a:i386
                                Depends: libghc-semigroupoids-prof-5.0.1-71922:i386
                                Depends: libghc-semigroups-prof-0.18.1-1d980:i386
                                Depends: libghc-tagged-prof-0.8.4-b253b:i386
                                Depends: libghc-transformers-prof-0.4.2.0-a5bbd:i386
                                Depends: libghc-transformers-compat-prof-0.4.0.4-8aa40:i386
                                Depends: libghc-void-prof-0.7.1-dfe8d:i386
 libghc-monadcatchio-transformers-dev:i386 : Depends: libghc-base-dev-4.8.2.0-a3ce8:i386
                                             Depends: libghc-extensible-exceptions-dev-0.1.1.4-81599:i386
                                             Depends: libghc-monads-tf-dev-0.1.0.3-8aa05:i386
                                             Depends: libghc-transformers-dev-0.4.2.0-a5bbd:i386
                                             Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.0) but it is not going to be installed
 libghc-monadcatchio-transformers-prof:i386 : Depends: libghc-base-prof-4.8.2.0-a3ce8:i386
                                              Depends: libghc-extensible-exceptions-prof-0.1.1.4-81599:i386
                                              Depends: libghc-monads-tf-prof-0.1.0.3-8aa05:i386
                                              Depends: libghc-transformers-prof-0.4.2.0-a5bbd:i386
 qdbus : Depends: qtchooser (>= 55-gc9562a1-1~)
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

`apt-get -f install` didn't help. What do I need to do to upgrade to Python 3.4.2?

Comment: you probably already have python 3. Try typing `python3` in your terminal and see which version you have.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I've just been informed that Python 3.4.2 isn't available for my distro

Comment: No, you've been informed that there is no package named `3.4.2`. The correct command would be `apt-get install python3=3.4.2` (which indeed may not exist - why would you install such an old version?) but this will not replace Python 2, because you cannot on Ubuntu, or Debian-based platforms generally.